# Cannot trim whitespace on email input

Tags: jquery

I was trying to trim trailing whitespace on an email input but believe there is an issue with trim being applied to email inputs. Can anyone explain why this is the case or whether I am incorrect in my assumptions. This code when applied works on the password field but not on the email field.

EDIT:

It is a Ruby on Rails application but the HTML created is like so:

View:

```
<input class="mandatory form-control form-control" id="user_email" maxlength="250" name="user[email]" required="required" type="email">
<input class="mandatory form-control form-control" id="user_password" maxlength="20" name="user[password]" required="required" type="password">
```

JQuery:

```
$('input').blur(function()
{
    this.value=$(this).val().trim();
});
```

I have also tried this but still no luck. It strips whitespace between text but still wont remove trailing whitespaces:

```
$('input[type=email]').on('blur', function () 
{
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/ /g,''));
})
```

Comment: Please pase some code here. It would help us to find the issue in your code, and solve it.

Comment: I have tried this on JSFiddle as well but the functionality doesn't seem to work on either. On my application it definitely is working on password and when i edit the code so the email input is just standard text input it works as well.

Answer (score 6):

When querying the value using `emailField.value` or `$(emailField).val()`, the value is already trimmed. From the [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#email-state-(type=email)):

> The value sanitization algorithm is as follows: Strip newlines from the value, then strip leading and trailing ASCII whitespace from the value.

Also, it doesn't update the displayed value if it is set to the same value. So we need to change the value and then change it back:

```
var trimmedValue = emailField.value;
emailField.value = '';
emailField.value = trimmedValue;
```

Or, with jQuery:

```
var trimmedValue = $(emailField).val();
$(emailField).val('').val(trimmedValue);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer and explains what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

Best approach I have found is:

```
$(function()
{
  $('input[type=email]').on('keypress', function(e)
  {
    if (e.which == 32)
      return false;
  });
});
```

All other approaches lead to strange behavior for input type email that lead to spaces still being presented. This approach stops the space appearing and because an email shouldnt have any spaces it works as hoped.

Comment: any clue how to reproduce this approach also for mobile devices keyboards?

Comment: this isn't going to work on pasted values

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I posted the wrong information earlier. Here is a working js code.

```
$('#user_email').bind('input', function()
{
    this.value=$(this).val().trim();
});
```

You can also use blur

```
$('#user_email').blur('input', function()
{
    this.value=$(this).val().trim();
});
```

Comment: Please read the very beginning of the question: "I was trying to trim trailing whitespace on an email input". The words trim, trailing and whitespace give an indication that I am not looking to remove all whitespace.

Comment: @EamonnMcElroy Sorry about that. I posted a new answer. Let me know if it works for you

Comment: @EamonnMcElroy Did this answer your issue? If so, please mark it as a answer. thank you

Comment: Still not covering it. Try it out yourself. When you press space it wont add a space but when you click out and back again the space you entered is present. As I said it is strange behavior which is why basic answers dont seem to cover it.

Answer (score 0):

I used the jquery version of 'trim' for this same type of field, and other fields and I was able to get **all** of them trimmed properly for Bootstrap (ver 3.xx) purposes. First, I set a class on all the fields that need **leading** and **ending** whitespace trimmed (but not 'internal' whitespace, like in "Van Camp"). Call it 'nowhite' for this example. So I set 'nowhite' as a class on whatever fields I want this to happen on in the form, like so:

```
enter code here
<div class="form-group">
         <input type="text" class="nowhite form-control" name="firstn" id="firstn" data-error="Must Enter First Name" required>
           <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
         <input type="text" class="nowhite form-control" name="lname" id="lname" data-error="Must Enter Last Name" required>
           <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>
```

In my jquery script, I have this:
     enter code here

```
$('.nowhite').focusout(function(e) {
    $(this).val(  $.trim($(this).val())) ;
});
```

I use it on a number of forms that have fields that are required and need something other than whitespace. I like it because it's short and seems intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Although the spaces were trimmed, the updated value from the input `type=email` was not put back in it's input control. However it does work if you put in a different value first and then put the trimmed value back.

```
<input type="text" value="VDWWD">
<input type="email" value="mail@domain.nl">

<script>
    $('input').bind('focusout', function () {
        var value = $(this).val().trim();

        //check for type=email and put dummy value in input
        if ($(this).prop('type') === 'email') {
            $(this).val('dummyvalue');
        }

        $(this).val(value);
    });
</script>
```